# open combo box on focus in a form (access 2013)

Tags: ms-access, combobox, ms-access-2013

I have a form that has a combo box with its values derived from the table, I am willing to make the combo box open on focus.

any help would be much appreciated.

btw, I am kind a new to Microsoft Access

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Private Sub SpecialCombox_GotFocus()

    Me.SpecialCombox.Dropdown

End sub
```

Comment: thank you so much for the quick answer,but could you be more specific on where should I put this code, as far as I know the combo box should be selected in design mode, in the "Property Sheet" the "On Get Focus" should do the trick, but after that I don't have a clue how to add a macro cause it opens a macro create window that I am not familiar with at all. If you could please give me more info on how to create the macro I would be so grateful.

Comment: select "[Event Proc]" for "On Get Focus" text box, then press  "..." button on the left. put line   Me.<HERE GOES name of your combo>.Dropdown()        and save changes

Comment: thanks again, after entering the string with my combo box ID, it gives me the following error: 

Compile Error: 
Expected:=

and the text turns red

Comment: remove () after Dropdown